# Cannot properly read a cookie

Tags: asp.net

I have a cookie bar that install a cookie called "CookiePolicy" to store user preferences (value = 1 states for OK, of course).

I need to use this value to activate/deactivate Google Analytics from my site.
I thought it was easy... but it's a real mess! :(

My code

```
<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   {
   HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("CookiePolicy");

   if( cookie.Value != "1" ){ 
      Response.Write("<script>");
      Response.Write("function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {");
      Response.Write("i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {");
      Response.Write("(i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)");
      Response.Write("}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),");
      Response.Write("m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)");
      Response.Write("})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');");
      Response.Write("ga('create', 'UA-xxxxx-x', 'auto');");
      Response.Write("ga('send', 'pageview');");

  }
} 

</script>
```

I receive all kind of errors. What's wrong??

The worst of them...
*System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*  (issued by the if clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CookiePolicy"];
```

For checking for null

```
if (cookie == null) {
   Response.Write("Cookie not found.");
}
```

Reference: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25045&seqNum=4

Comment: Your solution works fine, but at the end I decided to migrate the conditional process to a JS file. Thanks